# Can't return JSON field from Fetch response.json() (but can see it from console.log)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, fetch

I'm developing a Chrome extension and in my background.js i have a function

```
async function getData() {
  var resp = await (await fetch("https://www.example.com/json")).json();
  console.log(resp.field);
  alert(resp.field);
  return resp.field;
}
```

When i call the function (`var x = getData()`) alert and console.log show the content of the field (expected behavior), but then it returns a resolved Promise object. What am i missing?

Comment: "What am i missing?" Reading docs? Async function returns a promise, always.

Comment: Yeah, i've been going through it for a while but i couldn't wrap my head around it and i need a quick fix. How can i handle this returned promise so i get the field i need in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Async functions always return promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). Your `getData` function simply wraps `resp.field` into a resolved promise.

```
getData().then(field => console.log(field))
```